# How to stop page refresh on click of back button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="goBack($event);"> 
   Back
</button>
```

Model:

```
$scope.goBack = function ($event) {
   window.history.back();
   $event.preventDefault();
   $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Are you using `$state` ?

Comment: `window.history.back();` initiates the browser to go to previous page from the history which is impossible to control it, its API defined call. btw whats your expectation ?

Comment: As @dreamweiver says this will never work. Also, if you want to prevent default you have to pass it to the function: `goBack($event)`

Comment: if you are using `$state` then in your `$state.go` make `{ reload: false }`

Answer (score 1):

ui-router doesn't track the previous state once it transitions, but the event $stateChangeSuccess is broadcast on the $rootScope when the state changes.

You should be able to catch the prior state from that event (from is the state you're leaving)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState,
   toParams, from, fromParams) {
       $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
       $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Angularjs applications are single page applications so back should not refresh page. Although I suppose that the urls present have "#" present in them , so window.location.onhashchange event you can override.